# New Users and Answers that should be comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, comments

I have seen some answers that really should be comments, but the users who posted them do not have enough reputation (50) to comment on someone else's post.

What should we do with these kind of answers?  It doesn't seam like they should be voted down or deleted, just moved.

Could we add a way for a user with enough reputation to move another users answer to a comment?

Or what about a voting system, like close votes or re-open votes?

Comment: Is there anyway to reduce the amount of the amount of required reputation to post a comment? (This 'answer' is actually an example of this problem. I want to ask a followup question, but it really probably should be a comment.) I understand that spam is an issue, but it seems overly cumbersome for the moderators.

Comment: Unfortunately not. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment, you just have to wait until you earn the reputation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This mechanism is already in place. When you see an answer like that, click the "flag" button and select "it needs ♦ moderator attention > not an answer". Optionally, you can leave a comment explaining why the answer should be a comment. This will alert a moderator<sup>1</sup>. Moderators can convert the answer to a comment if they see fit.

As far as downvoting, it's probably best not to as long as the answer isn't blatant spam or such.

<sup>1</sup> In our case, an SE community manager would be alerted because we haven't yet chosen our pro-tem mods.